# Anchor 'a' tag's dynamically "href" link is not working right

Tags: html, asp.net

I am having problem while clicking on the image wrapped in an Anchor tag. The link is not appearing in  the proper order and it shows server error following is my code snippet.
have a look at this, am I doing something wrong

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" DataSourceID="datasource1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">                    
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="ads">
            <a href='<%# Eval("Link") %>' target="_blank">
                <asp:Image runat="server" Width="228" Height="189" ToolTip='<%# Eval("Description") %>' ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Image")) %>' />
            </a>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

if the Link is `www.example.com` then when I click on the image I get the following url along with `localhost/www.example.com` appended and it show a server error there.
so why not it navigates to this URL alone i have also used `resolveclienturl` method too.
kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: the issue could be the fact that an unqualified link is perceived as relative to the current url (the url of the page). if you put 'http://' in front of the link then the issue should go away.

Comment: That's definitely the right answer, why not post it as one?